# IONIC : Loading spinner while UI completes its rendering

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have about 1000 Ui components to render, Which includes ion-range,ion-select with JSON data. 
I am assigning my JSON Object array to the variable and rendering the components in HTML with *ngFor.

For e.g. :

```
In .ts :
let jsonArray=this.jsonData;

In .HTML :
<div *ngFor="let array of jsonArray">
// MY COMPONENTS
</div>
```

Now, I am getting data in variable ion less than 1ms. But my components taking so much time to render and it feels like screen is freezed.

Issue 1 : Can we reduce this rendering time by using anything other than this approach?

Issue 2 : Can we Add spinner or loading until its completes its rendering?

PS.: I am mentioning here that I have no issues with getting my data as it is from local sqliteDB. My Ui is getting stucked only while rendering the 1000 components.

**UPDATE of .ts file**

```
onSelect(dbId) {
    this.dbService.getData(dbId).then(data => {
    this.toDisplayArray=data.set;
  })
}
```

**Update of .HTML file**

```
<ion-select interface='popover' (ionChange)='onSelect($event.detail.value)'>
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let set of deviceList; let i of index" value="{{set.Id}}">
        {{set.name}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>

    <div *ngFor="let set of toDisplayArray;let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="set.type==="range">
    <range [id]="set.id" [title]="set.title"></range>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="set.type==="select">
    <select[id]="set.id" [title]="set.title"></select>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="set.type==="both">
    <range-select [id]="set.id" [title]="set.title"></range-select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

so range,select and range-select are selector of my child components where I am passing the data through input and output.

Comment: Can you show the `ts` code also? i.e. how to load the data?

Comment: Maybe you should look into pagination of your component. Why do you need to load 1000 components on the first load?

Comment: @TomasVancoillie Its requirement. And everytime I change option from ion-select its re-renders all 1000 components. Also I dont have any control on order in which they will get rendered.

Comment: @Sampath what do you want exactly from .ts? I am just assigning the variable to another variable after data recieved.

Comment: Need to see how you load the data for the components?

Comment: @Sampath updated in the question

Comment: This is not enough. How will you utilize `this.toDisplayArray` data on the page? You must show a few HTML components and their data binding workflow also.

Comment: Okay. I thought you need only .ts code

Comment: Is this a mobile-only app or will it use as a web app on big screens too?

Comment: use ion-infinite-scroll, it is best for load data without hanging or freezing the screen and smooth rendering

Comment: @Sampath Its for mobile only

Comment: @user9088454 Okay I will try

Comment: @user9088454 I used that but its not about scrolling. Once components rendered its scrolling well. But on select its taking time to get rendered.

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML for this event? `onSelect()`

Comment: @Sampath updated.

Comment: @AmitGandole you can check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923083/execute-function-after-dom-has-finished-rendering